# Change date from 2015/02/23 to "1 min ago"

Tags: date

So here is my code to display the post created date:

```
    $date_create = '<div class="mydate-created">';
    $date_create .= get_the_date('',$product->id);
    $date_create .='</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="mydate-created">';
    $output .= get_the_date('',$product->id);
    $output .= '</div>';
```

It displays the date of post created as the following "2015-02-23"

I know there is setting in the backend to change the date displayed.

However is there a way to display it like "1 min ago" or " 1 hour ago"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. This goes in `functions.php`

This changes the time on your website everywhere. Now you can keep using `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>` in your loop or theme files.

```
// Relative date & time
function wpse_relative_date() {
  return human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . ' ago';
}
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'wpse_relative_date' ); // for posts and pages
// add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wpse_relative_date' ); // for comments
```

I added a PHP comment before `add_filter` to also change comment dates too. Because I am not sure if you want that for comments too. Remove PHP comment if needed.

Comment: @steveKim If this is the answer you were searching for, please mark it as solution by ticking the checkmark below the voting arrows on the left of this answer.

Comment: Thank you. It was. I didn't know about the check mark. Thank you Robert! =)

Comment: :) I am glad I could help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<?php human_time_diff( $from, $to ); ?>` to return a human readable time difference.

Take a look at the Wordpress Codex [Function Reference/human time diff](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff).

Comment: Edited and code included.